# How to store in database info from spinner array adapters?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

What im trying to do is to get the info selected in my spinners into a sqlite database, and everithing looks good but when I debug my app and start this activity it stops working, here is my code:

```
    public class Materiales extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener  {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.materiales);

    Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;
    Button spb;

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp2);
    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp3);
    spb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.matb);

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.tirocarga_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.materiales_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.place_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spb.setOnClickListener(this);
       sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
      String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
      if(spinner.getId() == R.id.sp1)
      {

      DataBase entry = new DataBase(Materiales.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry1(selectedItem);
        entry.close();
      }
      else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.sp2)
      {
          DataBase entry = new DataBase(Materiales.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry2(selectedItem);
            entry.close();
      }
      else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.sp3)
      {
          DataBase entry = new DataBase(Materiales.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry3(selectedItem);
            entry.close();
      }
 }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

   }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.matb:

        startActivity(new Intent(this, Senprint.class));






         break;



}

}
```

Thanks for your help
 here is the log of the error
02-06 12:28:16.719: E/Trace(3861): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-06 12:28:20.243: E/SQLiteLog(3861): (1) near "TABLEcontent": syntax error
02-06 12:28:20.373: E/SQLiteLog(3861): (1) near "TABLEcontent": syntax error
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontent": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontent(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,fechaSTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,infoTEXT NOT NULL; materialesTEXT NOT NULL);
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.ipssum.coconal.DataBase$Dbhelper.onCreate(DataBase.java:39)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.ipssum.coconal.DataBase.open(DataBase.java:61)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.ipssum.coconal.Materiales.onItemSelected(Materiales.java:61)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4800)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
02-06 12:28:20.383: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: define "stop working". It throws an error?

Comment: Yes fatal error and the app just closes up

Comment: can you post the stack trace shown in logcat?

Comment: I posted the logcat above, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE content(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, fecha TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, info TEXT NOT NULL, materiales TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Please note the spacing between TABLE and content, and between other keywords in sql

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I fixed my database but the problem persist, I think the problem is from this part of the log (0612:28:20.383:E/AndroidRuntime(3861): at com.ipssum.coconal.Materiales.onItemSelected(Materiales.java:61)) to the end but I can´t solve it, thanks again

Comment: Can you post the Database.open() method

Comment: Thanks y fixed the problem it was right there, instead of implementing writable database a had a readable database, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From the trace it looks like you have problem with create table statement itself... Please cleanup the create table statement with proper spacing.